# Meteor aldeed:autoform-bs-datepicker: Month, Year Switch causes datepicker to freeze

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, datepicker, meteor-autoform

The Datepicker opens normally after clicking the Date field, selecting a date in the pre selected month is also possible. After trying to switch the Month or the year, the datepicker UI freezes. Also closing the datepicker after that is not possible. Disapears only after Ctrl+R reload.

In Template:

```
{> afQuickField name='profile.birthday' id="birthday"}}
```

In Schema:

```
birthday: {
    type: Date,
    autoform: {
        type: "bootstrap-datepicker",
        datePickerOptions: {
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
            autoclose: true
        }
    },
    optional: true
},
```

Versions:
Meteor                                       1.3.1
aldeed:autoform                              5.8.1
aldeed:autoform-bs-datepicker                1.1.1
rajit:bootstrap3-datepicker                  1.5.1
twbs:bootstrap                               3.3.6

Normaly i do not use the twbs:bootstrap package, i include it that way:
http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/meteorjs-and-twitter-bootstrap---the-right-way
[image: DatePicker Bug]

Any Ideas? 
Thanks!

Comment: I am working on a similar problem. I will post an answer if I can find one.